# Docker slow on OS X Symfony

Tags: docker

I have a basic Symfony4 setup and I have an issue with loading speed.

Currently I'm trying the docker-sync tool, it's up and running, but it seems that it doesn't do anything, speed stays the same.

Here is my current setup:

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'
services:
    apache:
        build: .docker/apache
        container_name: sf4_apache
        ports:
          - 80:80
        volumes:
          - .docker/config/vhosts:/etc/apache2/sites-enabled
          - .:/home/wwwroot/sf4
        depends_on:
          - php

    mysql:
      image: mysql
      command: "--default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password"
      container_name: sf4_mysql
      restart: always
      volumes:
        - ./data/db/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
      environment:
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
        MYSQL_DATABASE: sf4
        MYSQL_USER: sf4
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: sf4

    php:
        build: .docker/php
        container_name: sf4_php
        volumes:
          - .:/home/wwwroot/sf4
        environment:
          - maildev_host=sf4_maildev
        depends_on:
          - mysql
        links:
          - mysql

    phpmyadmin:
      image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
      container_name: sf4_phpmyadmin
      environment:
        PMA_HOST: mysql
        PMA_PORT: 3306
      ports:
        - 8080:80
      links:
        - mysql
```

docker-sync.yml

```
version: "2"

options:
  verbose: true
syncs:
  appcode-native-osx-sync: # tip: add -sync and you keep consistent names as a convention
    src: './'
    # sync_strategy: 'native_osx' # not needed, this is the default now
    sync_excludes: ['ignored_folder', '.ignored_dot_folder']
```

In this case I synced my entire Symfony application folder, but it doesn't help. docker-sync is up and running as well as all my containers, but performance is still slow. Any other ideas what could I do? I found that one of the solutions is to move the vendor folder out of shared files. How would I do that?

Comment: Hi, I guess you have a docker-compose-dev. yaml? If yes, could you share it? We set it up on a huge micro services Symfony project and we were impressed by the improved performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. More info about performance on MAC OS here https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/osxfs-caching/

So I mounted my volumes using *delegated* like this:

```
apache:
    build: .docker/apache
    container_name: sf4_apache
    ports:
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - .docker/config/vhosts:/etc/apache2/sites-enabled:delegated
      - .:/home/wwwroot/sf4:delegated
    depends_on:
      - php
```

Default skeleton Symfony 4 project now loads in less than 1 second. It is still kinda slow, but it's ten times faster than before. :)